# How to stop PM2 from passing previous node arguments?

Tags: node.js, pm2

For example, I did:
`pm2 restart 0 -- node-args="--DEBUG=true"`

It now seems to pass in those node args every time I do `pm2 restart 0`. I would like it to not pass those. Thanks!

Comment: Once upon a time it didn't, due to a bug. 
 https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/4029 But it seems it does so by design.

Comment: @Wyck that's... interesting. Really thought the behaviour would be the other way around. Thanks for that information